# System.Windows.Forms SendKeys escape keywords

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm attempting to send the **{** key using `SendKeys.SendWait(y)`. I'm passing a variable, *y* in this case, that has been set with a string containing **{**.

```
string y = "u8HXV/gIE_{";
SendKeys.SendWait(y);
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll 
but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Keyword delimiter is missing.
```

Is there a way of escaping this keyword **{** within SendKeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly brace is a special symbol for the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, so you need to *escape* it (treat it like special symbol) like this:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{{}");
```

The output is: **{**

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.